# Debian monitor unknown and dual monitor setup

Tags: debian, xorg, monitors

I'm running Debian on my laptop (Thinkpad T420 if it matters), and what I am trying to do is setup the native resolution. I want it to be 1366x768 but it's stuck at 1024x768 because when I go to Monitor Preferences, it says Monitor: Unknown. I've tried several things such as `xrandr --addmode VGA1 1366x768_60.00` and all the steps that contains that I've found on different websites. Some say remove `xorg.conf` but I don't have that in my X11 folder.

Have any of you guys encountered this problem before?

Also I'm trying to setup 2 monitors but again, they don't show up in Monitor Preferences.

Comment: Can you please provide the information provided via `xrandr`? Just run it and edit your post

Comment: @UlrichDangel Can't open display is what it says

Comment: it needs to be run inside your graphical environment as a normal user, just start a terminal/konsole and run xrandr